# Floating Action Button disappears when used with Navigation Drawer

Tags: android, navigation-drawer, material-design, floating-action-button

I'm using the following two libraries: [FAB](https://github.com/makovkastar/FloatingActionButton) for floating action button and [MaterialNavigationDrawer](https://github.com/neokree/MaterialNavigationDrawer) for Navigation Drawer.
When I use them individually, they work fine. But when I try to use both together, the FAB disappears.

Following is my main activity layout:

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:fab="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingLeft="10dp"
    android:paddingRight="10dp"
    android:paddingTop="12dp"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <fragment
        class="com.example.app1.fragments.OffersFragment"
        android:id="@+id/fragment_offer"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_offer" />

    <com.melnykov.fab.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|right"
        android:layout_marginBottom="14dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="4dp"
        android:elevation="6dp"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_place_white_24dp"
        fab:fab_colorNormal="@color/color_accent"
        fab:fab_colorPressed="@color/color_accent_pressed"
        fab:fab_colorRipple="@color/ripple" />

</FrameLayout>
```

Below is the layout for the offers fragment:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context="com.example.app1.fragments.OffersFragment">

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/rv_offers"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

    <include
        android:id="@+id/card_offer"
        layout="@layout/offer_card" />

</LinearLayout>
```

This is my init function which needs to be overriden while using MaterialNavigationDrawer.

```
public void init(Bundle bundle) {
    MaterialAccount account = new MaterialAccount(this.getResources(),
            "user","user@gmail.com",R.drawable.photo, R.drawable.navbar_header);
    account.setTitle("Title");
    this.addAccount(account);

    MaterialSection section = newSection("Share", R.drawable.ic_share_grey600_24dp, new OffersFragment());
    this.addSection(section);

    MaterialSection settingsSection = newSection("Settings", new OffersFragment());
    this.addBottomSection(settingsSection);
}
```